# Flutter Android Failed to start foreground service

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-background

I'm currently having issues with Flutter background service, the moment the app launches, it crashes within a few seconds. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />
```

**Errors**

> Failed to start foreground service due to SecurityException - have you
> forgotten to request a permission? - Starting FGS with type
> mediaProjection callerApp=ProcessRecord{b4e0284
> 12331:com.zioninvasion.prayer_buddy/u0a190} targetSDK=34 requires
> permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true
> [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION] any of the
> permissions allOf=false [android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT,
> android:project_media]

**MORE ERROR OUTPUT**

> D/AndroidRuntime(12331): Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime(12331):
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(12331): Process:
> com.zioninvasion.prayer_buddy, PID: 12331 E/AndroidRuntime(12331):
> android.app.RemoteServiceException$ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException:
> Context.startForegroundService() did not then call
> Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{c93a6db u0
> com.zioninvasion.prayer_buddy/id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService}
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.generateForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException(ActivityThread.java:2104)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2075)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException(Unknown
> Source:0) E/AndroidRuntime(12331):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2369)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) E/AndroidRuntime(12331):
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) E/AndroidRuntime(12331):
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331): Caused by: android.app.StackTrace: Last
> startServiceCommon() call for this service was made here
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1952)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1906)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:830)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api26Impl.startForegroundService(ContextCompat.java:1189)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService(ContextCompat.java:752)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> id.flutter.flutter_background_service.FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.start(FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.java:82)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> id.flutter.flutter_background_service.FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.java:121)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown
> Source:12) E/AndroidRuntime(12331):   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime(12331):  ... 6 more I/Process (12331): Sending
> signal. PID: 12331 SIG: 9

**Package of Interest**

```
flutter_background_service: ^5.0.5
```

Comment: Does anyone with a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Foreground Services

Foreground services are useful when you want to keep your app running in the foreground, even when the user switches to another app. This can be necessary for features like music players, GPS tracking, or ongoing notifications.
flutter_foreground_service

The flutter_foreground_service package enables you to create foreground services on Android and iOS devices. It allows you to display a persistent notification while your app performs its tasks in the foreground.

To add this package to your project, include it in your pubspec.yaml file:

**flutter_foreground_service: ^0.2.0**

instead of

**flutter_background_service: ^5.0.5**

Comment: pls don't put copy pasted chatGPT answers. Your answer doesn't even related to the issue of the author remotely

Comment: Please read the author's question and my answer more carefully.
The author is trying to start a foreground service using the foreground service permission and the background service package. These are different services, with different packages. To which I pointed out to him, what was wrong with my answer?

Comment: The author has clearly setup FGS and background service. The error is clearly mentioned in the stacktrack  as`RemoteServiceException$ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException`.

This error occurs when the fgs isn't started after 5 seconds of startForegroundService call. 
There could be various reasons this happens but this is a well documented problem people have faced (weirdly we are also facing this in some scenarios)